# How to correctly parse hash values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, hash

I have a helper method that calls an api. The api converts a text file to pdf, and responds with the original file path, the new file path, and the number of pages. The response from the api looks like this:

```
response = {"originalPath":"FILE_PATH", "previewPath":"DIFFERENT_PATH", "numPages":1}
```

From my understanding, I should be able to access the key values like this:

```
response[:numPages]
response[:previewPath]
```

However, when I try to parse the hash this way, I get a TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer). I'm pretty stumped by this response, any thoughts?

EDIT

This was actually working for me before, and I was parsing the response like this:

```
res = RestClient.post(uri.join,
{
    :file => File.new(file_path, 'rb')
})
response = []
response << res.split(/>(\d)</)[1]
response << res.split(/<previewPath>(L:\\MailFiles\\PDF\\sub_order_\d*\.pdf)/)[1]
response
```

As I said, this was working for me before, but now when I return that back to the calling controller, my response is:

```
[nil, nil]
```

Very confused by this.

EDIT

Now, I've changed the above to look like this:

```
response << res.body
```

Which looks like this:

```
["{\"originalPath\":\"L:\\\\MailFiles\\\\Originals\\\\file.plain\",\"previewPath\":\"L:\\\\MailFiles\\\\PDF\\\\sub_order_110986.pdf\",\"numPages\":1}"]
```

Which is obnoxious as hell, but at least I think I can parse that. Will keep updating, thanks for the comments people!

Comment: Can you pasted code for how you parsing the api response?

Comment: It depends on how it's being parsed. There's a difference between a HWIA and a plain Hash, e.g., `response['numPages']` should work if it's not a HWIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that ended up working is this:

```
res = []
res << response.body.split(/numPages":(\d)/)[1]
res = res[0].to_i
```

There's probably a great refactoring of this, if anyone more experienced wants to show me the light, but this works for now! Thanks again for the comments and answer.